# ENTITY FRAMEWORK Error al importar BBDD, certificación emitida por entidad sin confía

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

Hola a todos y ante todo gracias.

Tengo un proyecto de **consola en C#**.  Trabajo con **Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64 bits)** y tengo instalado unicamente el **SDK .NET 6**.

Por la parte de la BBDD trabajo con **SQL Server Management Studio 19.0**,  y con **Microsoft SQL Server Developer (64-bit)**. He creado una BBDD llamada **Proba** en **localhost**, con media docena de trablas sencillas (1Primerykey autoincremental y relaciones entre ellas por ID)

Mi objetivo era tratar de importar esta tabla a mi proyecto por medio de EntityFramework.

Para ello me he instalado 2 nugets.

```
microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlserver\7.0.2\
microsoft.entityframeworkcore.tools\7.0.2\
```

Hasta aquí todo bien.

Entonces para importar la BBDD, voy a **Herramientas** => **Administrador de paquetes NuGet** => **Consola del Administrador de paquetes** y trato de escribir la siguiente sentencia:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=localhost; Database=Proba Trusted_Connection=True 
TrustServerCertificate=True" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutPutDir 
Models/DB
```

A continuación aparecen los mensajes

```
Build started...
Build succeeded.
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A connection was successfully     
established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. 
(provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - La cadena de certificación fue emitida por una 
entidad en la que no se confía.)
etc....
etc....
etc....
etc....
ClientConnectionId:10d9c216-11eb-4695-9b27-e64edec43268
**Error Number:-2146893019,State:0,Class:20
A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error 
occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - La cadena de 
certificación fue emitida por una entidad en la que no se confía.)**
```

Y no me genera nada en mi proyecto.

Saben como puedo generar certificado de confianza SSL del proveedor (Entiendo que es SQL Server)?

Un saludo y gracias

Answer (score 4):

Proba con la siguiente cadena de conexion

```
"Server=localhost;Database=Proba ;Trusted_Connection=SSPI;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;Trust Server Certificate=true"
```

Comment: Muchissimas gracias!  Si me funciono a la primera!!

Answer (score 3):

La clave está en agregar la propiedad

```
TrustServerCertificate=True
```

en la cadena de conexión.

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, revisar [answer], saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Hola  lo que podes hacer para importar la cadena de conexión correcta es:

1-Visual Studio>Herramientas>Conectar a Base de datos

2-Elegir origen de datos , en este caso es:
Microsoft SQL Server

3-Elegir proveedor de datos:
Proveedor de datos Microsoft SqlCliente para SQL server

4-Click en Aceptar

5-Ir SqlServer Managment ,copiar el nombre el del servidor(Suele estar cuando ingresas SqlServer Managment,el programa solicita la autenticación, nombre del servidor,etc),volves al VisualStudio y pegas el nombre del servidor en el apartado de Nombre del Servidor .

6-En la opción de Cifrar, seleccionar Optional(False)

7-En el apartado de que dice "Establecer conexión con una base de datos" tenés que seleccionar el nombre de la base de datos

8-Proba conexión.

9-Haz click en Avazadas, casi al finalizar tenés toda conexión para usarla.

10-Por ultimo la copias y cancelas la conexión, y listo tenés la cadena de conexión para usar.
Espero que te sirva.